# Help with parametric quadratic equation

Tags: elementary-functions

We have the equation $x^2+ax+2a+1=0$ which has real roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ and a is a parameter. I need to answer to the following questions:

1. Find all values of a for which $x_1=(a-1)x_2$.
2. For which values of a the roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ are positive?

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\begin{align}
x_1+x_2&=-a\\
x_1 x_2 &= 2a+1
\end{align}$$

Comment: I know these formulae but I cant express $\frac{x_1}{x_2}$ in terms of a.

Comment: @chenh. Use the first expression to write $x_1$ in terms of $x_2$, then substitute it in $x_1=(a-1)x_2$.

Comment: And then? What do I do next?!

Comment: @chenh. You solve for $a$.

Comment: I got $x_2=-1$ is it true?

Comment: And  then $a=0$. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

1) $$x_1x_2=2a+1$$ $$\therefore x_2=\frac{2a+1}{x_1}$$ $$\therefore x_1=(a-1)\left(\frac{2a+1}{x_1}\right)$$ $$\therefore x_1^2=(a-1)(2a+1)$$
LHS is always greater than zero. $$\therefore (a-1)(2a+1)>0$$
From there, you will get the interval of $a$.

2) Just put RHS of $x_1+x_2$ and $x_1x_2$ greater than zero, you wll get the range of $a$.

Also, you have discriminant greater than zero. $$\therefore a^2-4(2a+1)>0$$ $$\therefore |a-4|>2\sqrt5$$

In the end, find the intersection of the range of values of $a$ from the answer and from the fact that discriminant is greater than zero.